# Should I test against warm cache or cold cache in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2012, query-performance, optimization

I'm tuning a query which runs slow the first time and fast on the subsequent runs. I understand that it is because SQL Server is using cold cache (reading from disk) the first time and using warm cache (reading from memory) the second time. When tuning queries in real-world scenarios should I tune using the warm cache or the cold cache? I've tried finding books or articles on this subject but couldn't find anything. Do you guys know of any resources that I can use to expand my knowledge on this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll pivot from David's answer a bit because I don't agree with the premise of the original question. I wouldn't specifically tune to either scenario. I would follow what actually happens in production and tune the queries that you've noticed are slow under the same conditions that make them slow.

Yes, ideally your data pages that are commonly used should be cached in Memory. But you may have the scenario that a query is routinely ran once a day / week / month / whatever, and it's pulling data from Disk. Or if you're working with *big data* which can be searched through any number of data pages, then you may see more data swapping in and out of your Memory cache.

Yes, you can buy more Memory for your server, but a more favorable approach would be to tune your queries (when possible), which costs nothing upfront.

An example of what I mean is, if you find a query in production that exhibits slowness when pulling data off Disk, but fast on subsequent runs once it's cached in Memory, you may want to look at the [I/O stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-io-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for a large number of [Physical Reads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/reading-pages) - the number of data pages being read from Disk (or large number of [Logical Reads](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/11/12/sql-server-what-is-logical-read/?amp) on the subsequent runs from cache). This may indicate your query is using Index Scans or Table Scans in its execution plan that could potentially be avoided by index tuning or query tuning. Or if it's an aggregative type of query, maybe a columnstore index would make more sense then whatever is currently being indexed.

My point is the behavior of slow off Disk, fast in Memory may indicate a potential query tuning opportunity that would've otherwise been missed if you chose to ignore that it's slow coming off Disk and only looked at it from a warm cache perspective, especially if it's usual that the data pages are not normally in the cache.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions! Much appreciated. When I run a query that involves two tables, does SQL Server read the entire copy of both tables from disk into memory or does it only read the rows that satisfy the join and where conditions?

Comment: @HanroRachel It depends on your execution plan. When everything is running smooth, and your plan is getting Index Seeks with the most optimal index, then it *should* only be loading the data pages that contain the data relevant for your query. If your query's execution plan is inefficient and using full Index Scans or Table Scans then the entire object is copied into Memory, which is why it may take longer on the first run. This can be determined by looking at the execution plan but also by looking at the Physical Reads / Logical Reads which are the number of data pages that were read.

Comment: The procedure i'm tuning runs takes a user id as input and returns specific records for them. So when 5000 users log in to our website and this procedure is called 5000 times, won't the engine have to get the pages into memory from disk 5000 times since it's different data every time? How does warm caching come into play in this scenario?

Comment: @HanroRachel Again it depends. Data pages are the data structure used to physically store the data. In SQL Server they are 8 KB big each. The smaller the *width* of your rows (less columns / smaller data types) the more rows can be stored in a single page. If the data needed from your `Users` table for User 1 is stored in the same data page as Users 2 through 1,000 then only 1 data page needs to be loaded off Disk and into Memory **once** for 1,000 different Users. And if the rest of your `Users` table's data was evenly distributed the same way, then only 5 data pages would be needed total.

Comment: thank you! How long do the data pages stay in memory? Is there something setting that determines it?

Comment: @HanroRachel No problem! It also depends on a number of factors based on how frequently those cached data pages are read from vs how much Memory pressure there is for other data pages that need to be cached, among other factors. Just a heads up, comments aren't meant for extended discussion, and I think your follow up questions would make for a good post on its own. Feel free to create a new post with any other related follow up questions regarding how data page caching works.

Answer (score 3):

Great question.  Always test with a warm cache, and measure the CPU, reads, and writes, not just the elapsed time.  Running with a cold cache is an unusual scenario, and really just measures your IO performance.

Comment: Thanks, David! Could you please provide any resources that delve more into this topic?

Comment: [DROPCLEANBUFFERS: A Better Test Of Storage Than Query Performance For SQL Server](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/dropcleanbuffers-a-better-test-of-storage-than-query-performance/)

Comment: @HanroRachel, note also the SQL Server storage engine [behaves differently](https://www.dbdelta.com/performance-testing-with-dbcc-dropcleanbuffers/) until the cache is warm.